# Can page derive from the another page in ASP NET Web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible in ASP.NET web pages to some page derive from the other page?

In example:

- I have `edit` page which allows to edit some content.
- I want to create `new` page which derive from `edit` and just
  override Save method.

Comment: Do you mean "site derive from the other site" or do you mean "page derive from the another page"?  In other words, are you talking about multiple projects, or multiple pages within the same project?

Comment: My mistake. I have just edited and corrected it.

Comment: You're also mixing up the view(html/aspx) with code behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want same functionality in two different pages why not create a User control and include in both the pages and toggle the logic for Save based on some property of User control.

You can check below url for example

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/user-control-example-how-to-create-and.html